# How to make a Fibonacci sequence with all the values ​below the input?

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I am trying to make a Fibonacci sequence where all the values ​​are below `N` where `N` is the input parameter. so I tried to do this but an error like this appears

```
TypeError: n1.slice is not a functionTypeError: n1.slice is not a function
```

this is so far I got:

```
function fib(N){
    let n1 = 1, n2 = 1, nextTerm;
    for (let i= 1; i < N; i++) {
            console.log(n1.slice(-1).pop())
            nextTerm = n1 + n2;
            n1 = n2;
            n2 = nextTerm;
        }
  }
fib(7)
```

my expectations when N = 7

```
1,1,2,3,5
```

and when N = 13

```
1,1,2,3,5,8
```

Hope you can help me to solve this

Comment: Why are you trying to `.slice` a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `nextTerm` in the condition of for loop instead of `i`.

```js
function fib(N) {
    let n1 = 1,
        n2 = 1,
        nextTerm = 0;
    console.log(n1)
    for (let i = 1; nextTerm < N; i++) {
        console.log(n2)
        nextTerm = n1 + n2;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = nextTerm;
    }
}
fib(7);
```